# Cracking when looping back audio on Intel DE1-SOC Board audio codec

Tags: audio, embedded, intel

I am trying to implment a loop back funciton on my Intel DE1-SOC board with the onboard audio codec with is the WM8731 chip.

I am using the tutorial code from here that gives you the base code and explains it to you: http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/MSO_de1_tutorials.html

When implementing the code I get a crackling noise on the output which is not the intended behvaiour. When I use a logic analyies I notice that there is some static on the ADC which will mean that there will be static produces on the DAC. See below for the output of the logic analyizer:

[image]

Where:

1. ctrl_clk: is a 12.5 MHz Signal that is used to run the audio codec
2. bclk: is the sampling rate the audio codec works at (48 khz)
3. dacdat: output data from the audio codec to the speaker port
4. daclrck: right left timer signal for deciding which side audio is output
5. adcdat: input data to the audio codec from the mic port
6. adclrck: right left timer signal for knowing which side audio is coming in from
7. sclk: clock for the i2c protocol when programming the codec
8. sdat: data line for i2c protocol

I have verified that my clock signals are indeed correct because the I2c behaour is occuring correctly and despite not wanting a crackling behaviour the codec is correctly producing the input channel to the output channel.

An interesting thing to note is that the cracking output behaviour occurs even when I have no mic plugged in so it is not an issue with my mic. I suspect it might be something to do with an internal signal with the codec but I have not found anything.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: 12.5 milli-Hertz seems way too slow for anything audio-related except maybe a very slow drum-beat or sample interval (80 second period).  Probably you meant MHz rather than mHz.

Comment: Are there volume controls in the sound chip for the analog input or output?  Are they supposed to affect the volume for loopback?  *Do* they affect the volume of the static you're seeing?  Does muting either input or output make it stop?  I don't know much about programming audio hardware, but perhaps that would help narrow down possible sources.

Comment: The post has been edited correcting the clock speed to MHz

Comment: Turns out I had the chip in slave mode wich cause it to produce a signal, but now I am not able to get the adcdat line to capture anything.

Answer (score 2):

The crackling sound has been eleminiated when I put the chip in slave mode which is the correct operating state for it. This had slipped my mind ealiler.

In slave mode the chip awaits signals from the input ports. In master mode the chip produces a signal on the adcdat line which is what was cause the crackling.